# Getting aggregate from Pandas for other categories

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform an aggregate calculation, but I want the calculation to apply to every other category.

So,

```
 df.groupby(['index']).agg({data : [func1,func2]})
```

Will perform the aggregate calculations func1 and func2 on the data grouped by index, but I want to perform the calculations on all the data that isn't in the index.

For example:

```
index data
A      1
A      2
A      1
B      2
B      2
B      4
B      4
C      1
C      3
D      4
D      1
```

I would want the results for A to be performed on the data in B,C,D.

Is there a novel way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I actually think I figured this out. Basically, I created a new dataframe and re-index'd it.

```
                value
original_index       
A                  44
A                  65
A                  88
B                  69
B                  11
B                  52
C                  56
C                  42
C                  85
D                  66
D                  77
D                   9
```

Loop through each index and and copy everything not in that index to a new dataframe. Then concat them all together.

```
l = []
for i in df.index.unique():
    d = df[~df.index.isin([i])].copy()
    d['new_index'] = i
    d.drop('original_index',axis=0,inplace=True)
    d.set_index('new_index',inplace=True)
    l.append(d)
df2 = pd.concat(l,axis=0)
```

Ouput:

```
           value
new_index       
A             69
A             11
A             52
A             56
A             42
A             85
A             66
A             77
A              9
B             44
B             65
B             88
B             56
B             42
B             85
B             66
B             77
B              9
C             44
C             65
C             88
C             69
C             11
C             52
C             66
C             77
C              9
D             44
D             65
D             88
D             69
D             11
D             52
D             56
D             42
D             85
```

Now we can apply our groupby function on the new index and it will return results from values that were originally not in the index.

```
group_df = df2.groupby(['new_index']).agg({'value' :[func1,func2]})[['value']]
```

It works, but I'm sure there must be a better way.